# Can we define a group structure on $[0,1]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can we define a group structure on $[0,1]$? I think $a*b=\{a+b\}$ where $\{.\}$ denotes fractional part function will define a group structure? Is there any other 'nice' way? For example, I know that we can transport group structure from $R$ into $(-1,+1)$ since there is a bijection between the two.

Comment: You can also use transport of structure from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$, as there are bijections between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a*b=\{a+b\}$ does not define a group structure on $[0,1]$ because $0*0=0$ implies $e=0$ which contradicts $0*1=0$.

$a*b=\{a+b\}$ *does* define a group structure on $[0,1)$. It's isomorphic to $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Or more obviously, because there would be two distinct identity elements.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this group operation is not continuous on $[0,1)$ with the usual topology. You need to give it the topology of a circle.